# parameters in lucene queries in neo4j repositories with SDN?

Tags: java, lucene, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I need to be able to search for substrings in a text field, via a parameterised repository method, in neo4j 1.9.5

Ideally I want to be able to call

```
getInteractionsByTermAndDateRange(String term,
        long startMillis, long endMillis
```

and get back every WRInteraction where the 'content' field contains 'term', with the pubMillis value within the specified range( 'content' is specified as a FULLTEXT index in the WRInteraction object declaration)

First attempt:

```
@Query("START  n=node:WRInteraction('content:*{0}*') " + " WHERE "
        + "    n.pubMillis >= {1} AND n.pubMillis <= {2}" + " RETURN "
        + "     n")
Iterable<WRInteraction> getInteractionsByTermAndDateRange(String term,
        long startMillis, long endMillis);
```

This throws

```
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'content:*{0}*': 
Encountered " "}" "} "" at line 1, column 11.
Was expecting one of:
"TO" ...
<RANGEEX_QUOTED> ...
<RANGEEX_GOOP> ...

at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:211) ~[lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40]
at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.IndexType.query(IndexType.java:300) ~[neo4j-lucene-index-1.9.5.jar:1.9.5]
```

Second try -- pass the whole lucene query  via the parameter:

```
@Query("START  n=node:WRInteraction('content:{0}') " + " WHERE "
        + "    n.pubMillis >= {1} AND n.pubMillis <= {2}" + " RETURN "
        + "     n")
```

doesn't fare any better... what's the pattern I should be using here? The key requirement is to be able to pass a substring to a repository method as a parameter, and return any WRInteractions where that substring is present int he 'content' field. Should be easy, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the lucene query as a whole.

```
@Query("START n=node:WRInteraction({0}) WHERE n.pubMillis >= {1} AND n.pubMillis <= {2} RETURN n")
Iterable<WRInteraction> getInteractionsByTermAndDateRange(String query,
        long startMillis, long endMillis);
```

Call this method like:

```
repository.getInteractionsByTermAndDateRange("content:*" + term + "*", 0, 0);
```